# What is the difference between `ORDER BY` and `PARTITION BY` arguments in the `OVER` clause?

Tags: window-functions

These queries below both give me exactly the same results, which I assume is because of my dataset rather than how the arguments work.

When using an `OVER` clause, what is the difference between `ORDER BY` and `PARTITION BY`.

On a slightly different note, why not use the term `GROUP BY` instead of the more complicated sounding `PARTITION BY`, since it seems that using partitioning in this case seems to achieve the same thing as grouping. I know you can alter these inner partitions and that those changes then reflect in the table. Is that the reason?

Query 1:

```
SELECT
    CP.iYear,
    AVG(AVG(CP.mUpgradeCost)) OVER(ORDER BY iYear) AS [avg]
FROM ProForma.dbo.CapitalProject CP
GROUP BY CP.iYear
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
    CP.iYear,
    AVG(AVG(CP.mUpgradeCost)) OVER(PARTITION BY iYear) AS [avg]
FROM ProForma.dbo.CapitalProject CP
GROUP BY CP.iYear
```

Comment: FYI, this is related to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168028/sql-server-what-is-the-default-window-an-aggregate-function-is-applied-to

Comment: If you're really interested in learning about Window functions, Itzik Ben-Gan has a couple great books (High Performance T-SQL Using Window Functions, and T-SQL Querying). I highly recommend them both.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `PARTITION BY` works as a "windowed group" and the `ORDER BY` does the ordering within the group. However, because you're using `GROUP BY CP.iYear`, you're effectively reducing your window to just a single row (`GROUP BY` is performed *before* the windowed function). The average of a single row will be the value of that row, in your case `AVG(CP.mUpgradeCost)`.

As for query 2, are you trying to create a running average or something? Not even sure what you would expect that query to return.

If you remove `GROUP BY CP.iYear` and change `AVG(AVG(...))` to just `AVG()`, you'll see the difference.

Here's an example that will hopefully explain the use of `PARTITION BY` and/or `ORDER BY`:

Random table:

```
a     b
----- ------
X     1001
X     1002
X     1003
Y     1001
Y     1002
```

Now,

```
SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a) FROM r;
```

will return

```
a     b
----- ------ ------
X     1001   3
X     1002   3
X     1003   3
Y     1001   2
Y     1002   2
```

So you can see that there are 3 rows with a=X and 2 rows with a=Y. The `ORDER BY` clause comes into play when you want an *ordered* window function, like a row number or a running total.

```
SELECT a, b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b),
             SUM(b) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM r;
```

... gives you:

```
a     b
----- ------ ------ ------
X     1001   1      1001
X     1002   2      2003
X     1003   3      3006
Y     1001   1      1001   <- row number and running total resets here; new partition
Y     1002   2      2003
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no use case for my code above other than understanding how the SQL is working